# Capifony: repository on the production server

Tags: php, git, symfony, capifony

I have **Capifony** config:

```
set :application, "AppName"
set :name,        "appName"
set :domain,      "myServer"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/appname"
set :app_path,    "app"

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:myname/repoapp.git"
set :scm,         :git
```

and it works fine. But I want copy files from repository which on the same production server **myServer** (~/repoapp.git).

Something like:
`set :repository,  "myServer:~/repoapp.git"`

It shows error:

```
    servers: ["myServer"]
    [myServer] executing command
 ** [myServer :: out] ssh: Could not resolve hostname myServer: No address associated with hostname
 ** [myServer :: out]
 ** [myServer :: out] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 ** [myServer :: out]
 ** [myServer :: out]
 ** Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 ** and the repository exists.
```

**SSH config**:

```
Host myServer
Hostname 192.241.xxx.xxx
User root
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/digital_ocean
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to use local git repository that is located on same server where you are deploying

you can do it as

```
set :repository, "file:///srv/git/repoapp.git"
set :local_repository, "file://."
```

Comment: How it should look like if the full path to repository is **/root/repoapp.git** ?

Comment: set :repository, "file:///root/repoapp.git"

Comment: I have error `fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax`

Comment: pls show me your git config file: /root/repoapp.git/config

Comment: `[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = true`

Comment: git remote add origin 'git@bitbucket.org:myname/repoapp.git'

Comment: Same error: `fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax` :(

Comment: and what is content for  /root/repoapp.git/config ?

Comment: `[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = git@bitbucket.org:myname/repoapp.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: add pls "set   :deploy_via,       :capifony_copy_local"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98976/discussion-between-max-lipsky-and-evgeniy-kuzmin).